# Android and JavaScript, JS how to get webview JS return data?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

We know Android studio can get invoke the html javascript since Android API17,

```
ERPWebViewJsInterface erpWebViewJsInterface = new ERPWebViewJsInterface(this);
erpWebViewJsInterface.setmWebViewJSCallBack(this);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(erpWebViewJsInterface, WebViewParams.WEBVIEWW_JS_FLAG);
```

Sometimes, we may need return data to html ,But the Javascript how to get the data?

I think, maybe we can in javascript define  resultCallBack, when we get the result, we can invoke the Javascript method!

Do you have the better method! get the Android method return data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `addJavaScriptInterface` is meant to call Java functions from JavaScript.

To call JavaScript code from Java you can't use that. You might want to use `loadUrl` instead.

For example:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hey there!')");
```

You can replace the alert call with whatever code you need.

You could also do something similar using Apache Cordova. It allows you to call Java Plugins from JavaScript. You can pass a callback to a Cordova plugin, have the plugin cache the callback, and then run it from Java whenever you need it.